# SASS using & for parent and that parent is first-child

Tags: sass

I know you can specify if an element has a specific parent using `&`:

```
.btn {
    .btn-group & {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

But can you also say if the parent is btn-group and .btn-group is the first child?

Something like:

```
.btn {
    .btn-group & &:first-child {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out that I can do:

```
.btn {
    .btn-group:first-child & {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

But couldn't find a way to have multiple pseudo selectors (except using the above syntax with comma separated):

```
// This doesn't work :(
.btn {
    .btn-group & {
        &:first-child,
        &:last-child {
            color: blue;
        }
    }
}
```